# C++ global namespace members already defined error

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a namespace and its members available globally however I am running into `already defined` errors.

**Settings.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp"
#include <string>

using json = boost::property_tree::ptree;
namespace Settings {

    extern std::string settingsPath;
    extern json settings;

    extern void init();
    extern void readSettings();
    extern void writeSettings();
};
```

**Settings.cpp**

```
#pragma once

#include "Settings.h"

using json = boost::property_tree::ptree;

namespace Settings {

    void init() {

    }

    void readSettings() {

    }

    void writeSettings() {

    }
};
```

I am forward declaring the `Settings` namespace and members and using `extern`. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Please could someone point out the error here.

Thanks

Edit: The actual error messages:

```
Error   LNK2005 "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class 
        std::allocator<char> > Settings::settingsPath" (?settingsPath@Settings@@3V?$
        basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@A) already defined in 
        AmalgamService.obj  Amalgam F:\Dropbox\CPP\Visual Studio Projects\Amalgam\Amalgam\
        main.obj    1
```

And repeat for all members of the namespace. The `Settings.h` is `#include`ed in `main.cpp` and `AmalgamService.cpp`

Comment: Please copy and paste the actual error messages into the question. And you don't need to `extern` declare functions.

Comment: unrelated. No need to `#pragma once` the cpp file. If you are including cpp files you've got bigger problems coming.

Comment: Added the error message. Also thanks for the `#pragma once` info. I don't include the cpp files so only a minor problem here

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be including `Settings.cpp` in another file. Do not include `.cpp` files. This results in duplicate definitions. This also means that `#pragma once` in `.cpp` files is useless.

You need to keep in mind that `#include` is just a glorified copy&paste tool. When you `#include` a file, that file is literally being copy&pasted into the spot of the `#include` statement. So including a `.cpp` file means you will get multiple definitions of everything defined in that `.cpp` file.

Furthermore, you don't have to use `extern` when declaring functions. Functions are `extern` by default, unless you say otherwise.

Variables are `extern` by default too, however you need to use `extern` as a way to declare them without defining them:

```
extern int var; // declaration
int var; // definition
```

Functions don't need that, because you can declare them by omitting their body:

```
void func(); // declaration
void func() { } // definition
```

You are allowed to declare things multiple times, which is why you can `#include` header files (like `.h`, `.hpp`) in multiple files. But you are not allowed to define things multiple times, which is why you can't `#include` non-header source files.